# Ensuring generic wildcards match in Java

Tags: java, generics

So it is my understanding that the following:

```
HashMap<Class<?>,List<?>> map
```

would allow you to insert any pairing. How do I enforce it so that you can only insert matched pairs. e.g.

```
map.put(String.class, new Vector<String>());
map.put(Integer.class, new Vector<Integer>());
```

But disallow the following:

```
map.put(ClassA.class, new Vector<ClassB>()); //I want this to refuse to compile
```

Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the input so far. I understand abstracting away the map insertion to enforce a common type across both parameters. This will keep the map clean, BUT how can I then guarantee to the compiler that this is the case.

E.g. this will cause a compiler grumble, and no amount of casting seems to fix it (at least that I've tried)

```
List<String> list1 = map.get(String.class);
```

so instead I'm currently using the following but I'm not too happy with it

```
List list2 = map.get(String.class);
```

NB I'm not currently in front of an IDE so this is from memory but hopefully the general idea is clear.

Comment: Where is `map` declared and instantiated? Is there a common superclass or interface implemented by the potential classes (except for `Object`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not directly use a `HashMap`, as the default methods it has will not allow for what you desire. I'd write my own collection based on the `HashMap` that would expose it's own `put` method. It will probably look like this:

```
public <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list) {
    internalMap.put(clazz, list);
}
```

Assume the `internalMap` is a private member of this collection class and is of type `HashMap<Class<?>, List<?>>`. Notice the use of generic parameter to the method. You could call this like that:

```
myCollection.<Integer>put(Integer.class, new Vector<Integer>());
myCollection.<String>put(String.class, new Vector<String>());
```

or even like that:

```
myCollection.put(Integer.class, new Vector<Integer>());
myCollection.put(String.class, new Vector<String>());
```

these then will not compile:

```
myCollection.<String>put(String.class, new Vector<Integer>());
myCollection.put(String.class, new Vector<Integer>());
```

---

**Update** regarding the [latest comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061313/ensuring-generic-wildcards-match-in-java/23061433?noredirect=1#comment35245190_23061433) on my question, and the [update of the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23061313/2):

> How would I make this more generic. e.g. replace List with a generic type defined at class level. Something like public  void put (Class clazz, T1 t1)...how do you ensure that T1 can handle a generic parameter?

Well, you can still do this, with an additional generic parameter and a **type constraint**. You need to use a root base class or interface for the collection you would like to have, because we need to *enforce* the generics appropriately. Let's assume that base type is the [`Collection<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface (`Vector`, `ArrayList` and many other collections implement this interface). The above `put` method would look like this (I am including an imaginary class with the `internalMap` definition):

```
public class ClassMap {

    private Map<Class<?>, Collection<?>> internalMap 
        = new HashMap<Class<?>, Collection<?>>();

    public <T, TCollection extends Collection<T>> void put(
            Class<T> clazz, 
            TCollection collection) {
        internalMap.put(clazz, collection);
    }

    public <T> Collection<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
        // Notice the cast, it is important as it will hide
        // the "compiler grumble" you mention in your post
        return (Collection<T>) internalMap.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

The usage would slightly update for the cases with explicit generic arguments:

```
myCollection.<Integer, Vector<Integer>>put(Integer.class, new Vector<Integer>());
myCollection.<String, ArrayList<String>>put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());
```

and the shorter version:

```
myCollection.put(Integer.class, new Vector<Integer>());
myCollection.put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());
```

will also work, due to the **generic type inference**.

The `get` method, as you must have noted, uses the `Collection<T>` interface. If we introduce a `TCollection` generic argument in the same manner as in the put method, you will now have to always supply the generic arguments. So, if the get method was defined like this:

```
public <T, TCollection extends Collection<T>> TCollection get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (TCollection) internalMap.get(clazz);
}
```

then you have **2 problems**:

- The call now needs some **necessary ugliness**:

```
ArrayList<String> list 
 = myCollection.<String, ArrayList<String>>get(String.class);
```

- You have **no compile-time guarantee** that the collection is really an `ArrayList<String>` (and I am thinking compile-time type safety is important to you), so you will receive a runtime-exception for invalid cast if you are wrong. Therefore, the `get` method does not need to introduce the `TCollection` generic argument at all, it is guaranteed to work well with the `Collection<T>` interface (as all values will eventually implement it). If that interface is not suitable for you (you need specific methods of it and etc), you'd probably have either to cast it explicitly (with the risks in mind), or use a more-concrete interface as a root type for the constraint of the `TCollection`. For instance, instead of `Collection<T>`, you can use `List<T>`.

As a bottom line, regarding the use of the `TCollection` generic argument, it can be omitted. Once you add a collection to the map, you will no longer know the exact implementation you used. So, the above code will effectively be the same as this:

```
public class ClassMap {

    private Map<Class<?>, Collection<?>> internalMap 
        = new HashMap<Class<?>, Collection<?>>();

    public <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, Collection<T> collection) {
        internalMap.put(clazz, collection);
    }

    public <T> Collection<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (Collection<T>) internalMap.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

and will be used simply like that:

```
myCollection.<Integer>put(Integer.class, new Vector<Integer>());
myCollection.<String>put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());
```

or like that:

```
myCollection.put(Integer.class, new Vector<Integer>());
myCollection.put(String.class, new Vector<String>());
```

That is the same as [kocko's suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061313/ensuring-generic-wildcards-match-in-java/23061394#23061394)

Comment: The `internalMap` has to be parametrized with the same type `T`, as the one defined in the method signature. Since it turnes out that the `internalMap` is a class member, I would define the generic `T` type on class level. :)

Comment: @kocko, nice pointing that out, I have forgotten to mention what the type of my `internalMap` is (now fixed). Of course, it would not use the generic `T` as it would be violated, so it would therefore use the `?` placeholder.

Comment: How would I make this more generic. e.g. replace List with a generic type defined at class level. Something like public <T> void put (Class<T> clazz, T1<T> t1)...how do you ensure that T1 can handle a generic parameter?

Comment: @overclockwise, checkout my update, I have addressed your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a generic type (let's say in the scope of the enclosing method) and use it as a type for the generic `Class` and the generic `Vector` (or even better, a generic `Collection`).

```
public <T> void method(Class<T> clazz, Collection<T> collection) {
    Map<Class<T>,Collection<T>> map = new HashMap<Class<T>, Collection<T>>();
    map.put(clazz, collection); //this will compile
}
```

You can invoke it with:

```
method(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());
//or
method(String.class, new Vector<String>());
```

and you can note that this statement doesn't compile:

```
method(Integer.class, new Vector<String>());
```

Comment: Actually, it would be `<String>method();`. I myself often get this confused too, as I come from .NET background.

Comment: It doesn't even require the `<String>` piece in my example. I edited it. Thanks :)